# Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (not a xsl import or include issue)

Tags: xslt

I have two xsl files; both of them perform different tasks on source xml one after another. Now I need a single xsl file which will actually perform both these tasks in single file (its not an issue of xsl import or xsl include):

Say my source xml is:

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
    <R7P1_1>
        <LVL2>
            <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>#+#</ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
            <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
            <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>#+#</GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
            <CREDIT_DER/>
        </LVL2>
        <LVL21>
            <AZ>#+#</AZ>
            <BZ>bz1</BZ>
            <AZ>az2</AZ>
            <BZ>#+#</BZ>
            <CZ/>
        </LVL21>
    </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

My **first xsl (tr1.xsl) removes all nodes whose value is blank or null:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:if test=". != '' or ./@* != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **output** here is

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
    <R7P1_1>
        <LVL2>
            <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>#+#</ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
            <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
            <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>#+#</GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
        </LVL2>
        <LVL21>
            <AZ>#+#</AZ>
            <BZ>bz1</BZ>
            <AZ>az2</AZ>
            <BZ>#+#</BZ>
        </LVL21>
    </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

And **my second xsl (tr2.xsl) does a global replace (of #+# with text blank'') on the output of first xsl:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">
    <xsl:template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:param name="outputString"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($outputString,$target)">
                <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(substring-before($outputString,$target),
               $replacement)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="outputString"
             select="substring-after($outputString,$target)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement"
             select="$replacement"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'#+#'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="''"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So my **final output is**

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
    <R7P1_1>
        <LVL2>
            <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV></ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
            <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
            <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT></GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
        </LVL2>
        <LVL21>
            <AZ></AZ>
            <BZ>bz1</BZ>
            <AZ>az2</AZ>
            <BZ></BZ>
        </LVL21>
    </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

My concern is that instead of these two xsl (tr1.xsl and tr2.xsl) I only need a single xsl (tr.xsl) which gives me final output?

Say when I **combine these two as**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:if test=". != '' or ./@* != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:param name="outputString"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($outputString,$target)">
                <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(substring-before($outputString,$target),
               $replacement)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="outputString"
             select="substring-after($outputString,$target)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement"
             select="$replacement"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'#+#'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="''"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**it outputs:**

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
    <R7P1_1>
        <LVL2>
            <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV></ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
            <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
            <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT></GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
            <CREDIT_DER/>
        </LVL2>
        <LVL21>
            <AZ></AZ>
            <BZ>bz1</BZ>
            <AZ>az2</AZ>
            <BZ></BZ>
            <CZ/>
        </LVL21>
    </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

Only replacement is performed but not null/blank node removal.

Comment: Hi Flack help required again on the same problem, please check the my question once again (at the end of the question I have added the further problem).

Comment: Flack please look into my new question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646329/merge-functionality-of-two-xsl-files-into-a-single-file-continued

Comment: Please, don't repost questions and don't mix markup, use `<CODE>` or `{}` edit buttom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'#+#'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="''"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="*[not(text()) and not(*) and not(@*)]"/>

<xsl:template name="globalReplace">
    <xsl:param name="outputString"/>
    <xsl:param name="target"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($outputString,$target)">
            <xsl:value-of
                    select="concat(
                    substring-before($outputString,$target)
                    ,$replacement)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
                <xsl:with-param name="outputString"
                                select="substring-after($outputString,$target)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$outputString"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this well-formed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST_R7P1_1>
  <R7P1_1>
    <LVL2>
        <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>#+#</ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
        <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
        <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>#+#</GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
        <CREDIT_DER/>
    </LVL2>
    <LVL21>
        <AZ>#+#</AZ>
        <BZ>bz1</BZ>
        <AZ>az2</AZ>
        <BZ>#+#</BZ>
        <CZ/>
        <ONE_MORE_TEST>#+#OLOLO</ONE_MORE_TEST>
    </LVL21>
  </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

Produces this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST_R7P1_1>
  <R7P1_1>
    <LVL2>
        <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV/>
        <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
        <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT/>
    </LVL2>
    <LVL21>
        <AZ/>
        <BZ>bz1</BZ>
        <AZ>az2</AZ>
        <BZ/>
        <ONE_MORE_TEST>OLOLO</ONE_MORE_TEST>
    </LVL21>
  </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the output should not remove the node containing value #+# but should make it null node as <AZ>#+#</AZ> should become <AZ></AZ>; only nodes with null value say <CREDIT_DER/> should be completely removed from xml.


So final output should be :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<LIST_R7P1_1>
 <R7P1_1>
  <LVL2>
   <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV></ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV>
   <EXP_AFT_CONV>abc</EXP_AFT_CONV>
   <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT></GUARANTEE_AMOUNT>
  </LVL2>
  <LVL21>
   <AZ></AZ>
   <BZ>bz1</BZ>
   <AZ>az2</AZ>
   <BZ></BZ>
  </LVL21>
 </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>

Comment: Just remove _or text() = '#+#'_. I will edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: Here, at SO, we express our gratitude by accepting and upvoting the answer (checkmark in the top left of my answer).

Answer (score 4):

The general solution to the problem is to change the template rules and apply-templates calls in one stylesheet to use mode M1, and those in the other to use mode M2, and then to combine them like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="M1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp" mode="M2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But in XSLT 1.0 the second apply-templates will need to be

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp)" mode="M2"/>
```

Comment: But why "pipeline" them if OP stated (well, not obviously), that they can be merged manually?

Comment: @Flack: Pipelining is better than manual merging -- the former can be automated while for the latter one has to go through all phases of development again. In any more than trivial case pipelining takes only negligible amount of effort compared to manual merging. Another big advantage of pipelining is that it allows code-reuse.