# Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (continued.....)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is in continuation of my question:

[Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (not a xsl import or include issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644594/merge-functionality-of-two-xsl-files-into-a-single-file-not-a-xsl-import-or-incl)

---

**I have to merge the solution (xsl) of above question to below xsl:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <Declaration>
      <Message>
        <Meduim>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Message/Meduim"/>
        </Meduim>
        <MessageIdentifier>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Message/MessageIdentifier"/>
        </MessageIdentifier>
        <ControlingAgencyCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Message/ControlingAgencyCode"/>
        </ControlingAgencyCode>
        <AssociationAssignedCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Message/AssociationAssignedCode"/>
        </AssociationAssignedCode>
        <CommonAccessReference>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Message/CommonAccessReference"/>
        </CommonAccessReference>
      </Message>
      <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/BeginingOfMessage/MessageCode"/>
        </MessageCode>
        <DeclarationCurrency>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/BeginingOfMessage/DeclarationCurrency"/>
        </DeclarationCurrency>
        <MessageFunction>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/BeginingOfMessage/MessageFunction"/>
        </MessageFunction>
      </BeginingOfMessage>
      <Header>
        <ProcessingInformation>
          <xsl:for-each select="/Declaration/Header/ProcessingInformation/ProcessingInstructions">
            <ProcessingInstructions>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ProcessingInstructions>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ProcessingInformation>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Declaration/Header/Seal">
          <Seal>
            <SealID>
              <xsl:value-of select="SealID"/>
            </SealID>
            <SealLanguage>
              <xsl:value-of select="SealLanguage"/>
            </SealLanguage>
          </Seal>
        </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference = ""'>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A</xsl:text>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference"/>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Declaration/Header/Items">
          <Items>
            <CustomsStatusOfGoods>
              <CPC>
                <xsl:value-of select="CustomsStatusOfGoods/CPC"/>
              </CPC>
              <CommodityCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="CustomsStatusOfGoods/CommodityCode"/>
              </CommodityCode>
              <ECSuplementaryMeasureCode1>
                <xsl:value-of select="CustomsStatusOfGoods/ECSuplementaryMeasureCode1"/>
              </ECSuplementaryMeasureCode1>
              <ECSuplementaryMeasureCode2>
                <xsl:value-of select="CustomsStatusOfGoods/ECSuplementaryMeasureCode2"/>
              </ECSuplementaryMeasureCode2>
              <PreferenceCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="CustomsStatusOfGoods/PreferenceCode"/>
              </PreferenceCode>
            </CustomsStatusOfGoods>
            <xsl:for-each select="ItemAI">
              <ItemAI>
                <AICode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="AICode"/>
                </AICode>
                <AIStatement>
                  <xsl:value-of select="AIStatement"/>
                </AIStatement>
                <AILanguage>
                  <xsl:value-of select="AILanguage"/>
                </AILanguage>
              </ItemAI>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <Locations>
              <CountryOfOriginCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="Locations/CountryOfOriginCode"/>
              </CountryOfOriginCode>
              <xsl:for-each select="Locations/ItemCountryonRouteCode">
                <ItemCountryonRouteCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </ItemCountryonRouteCode>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <ItemDispatchCountry>
                <xsl:value-of select="Locations/ItemDispatchCountry"/>
              </ItemDispatchCountry>
              <ItemDestinationCountry>
                <xsl:value-of select="Locations/ItemDestinationCountry"/>
              </ItemDestinationCountry>
            </Locations>
            <Measurements>
              <GrossMass>
                <xsl:value-of select="Measurements/GrossMass"/>
              </GrossMass>
              <NetMass>
                <xsl:value-of select="Measurements/NetMass"/>
              </NetMass>
              <SupplementaryUnits>
                <xsl:value-of select="Measurements/SupplementaryUnits"/>
              </SupplementaryUnits>
              <ThirdQuantity>
                <xsl:value-of select="Measurements/ThirdQuantity"/>
              </ThirdQuantity>
            </Measurements>
            <xsl:for-each select="Package">
              <Package>
                <PackageNumber>
                  <xsl:value-of select="PackageNumber"/>
                </PackageNumber>
                <PackageKind>
                  <xsl:value-of select="PackageKind"/>
                </PackageKind>
                <PackageMarks>
                  <xsl:value-of select="PackageMarks"/>
                </PackageMarks>
                <PackageLanguage>
                  <xsl:value-of select="PackageLanguage"/>
                </PackageLanguage>
              </Package>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <PriceValue>
              <ItemStatisticalValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="PriceValue/ItemStatisticalValue"/>
              </ItemStatisticalValue>
              <ItemPrice>
                <xsl:value-of select="PriceValue/ItemPrice"/>
              </ItemPrice>
            </PriceValue>
            <ItemReferences>
              <xsl:for-each select="ItemReferences/ContainerID">
                <ContainerID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </ContainerID>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <QuotaNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemReferences/QuotaNo"/>
              </QuotaNo>
              <UNDangerousGoodsCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemReferences/UNDangerousGoodsCode"/>
              </UNDangerousGoodsCode>
            </ItemReferences>
            <GoodsDescription>
              <GoodsDescription>
                <xsl:value-of select="GoodsDescription/GoodsDescription"/>
              </GoodsDescription>
              <GoodsDescriptionLanguage>
                <xsl:value-of select="GoodsDescription/GoodsDescriptionLanguage"/>
              </GoodsDescriptionLanguage>
            </GoodsDescription>
            <Documents>
              <xsl:for-each select="Documents/PreviousDocument">
                <PreviousDocument>
                  <PreviousDocumentKind>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PreviousDocumentKind"/>
                  </PreviousDocumentKind>
                  <PreviousDocumentIdentifier>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PreviousDocumentIdentifier"/>
                  </PreviousDocumentIdentifier>
                  <PreviousDocumentType>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PreviousDocumentType"/>
                  </PreviousDocumentType>
                  <PreviousDocumentLanguage>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PreviousDocumentLanguage"/>
                  </PreviousDocumentLanguage>
                </PreviousDocument>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="Documents/ItemDocument">
                <ItemDocument>
                  <DocumentCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentCode"/>
                  </DocumentCode>
                  <DocumentPart>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentPart"/>
                  </DocumentPart>
                  <DocumentQuantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentQuantity"/>
                  </DocumentQuantity>
                  <DocumentReason>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentReason"/>
                  </DocumentReason>
                  <DocumentReference>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentReference"/>
                  </DocumentReference>
                  <DocumentStatus>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentStatus"/>
                  </DocumentStatus>
                  <DocumentLanguage>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DocumentLanguage"/>
                  </DocumentLanguage>
                </ItemDocument>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </Documents>
            <Valuation>
              <ValuationMethodCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="Valuation/ValuationMethodCode"/>
              </ValuationMethodCode>
              <ItemValuationAdjustmentCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="Valuation/ItemValuationAdjustmentCode"/>
              </ItemValuationAdjustmentCode>
              <ItemValuationAdjustmentPercentage>
                <xsl:value-of select="Valuation/ItemValuationAdjustmentPercentage"/>
              </ItemValuationAdjustmentPercentage>
            </Valuation>
            <ItemTransportChargeMOP>
              <xsl:value-of select="ItemTransportChargeMOP"/>
            </ItemTransportChargeMOP>
            <xsl:for-each select="ItemProcessingInstructions">
              <ItemProcessingInstructions>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </ItemProcessingInstructions>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Items>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <NumberOfPackages>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Header/NumberOfPackages"/>
        </NumberOfPackages>
      </Header>
    </Declaration>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so **for source xml**

```
<Declaration>
    <Message>
        <Meduim>#+#</Meduim>
        <MessageIdentifier>AA</MessageIdentifier>
        <CommonAccessReference></CommonAccessReference>
    </Message>
    <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>ISD</MessageCode>
        <DeclarationCurrency></DeclarationCurrency>
        <MessageFunction>5</MessageFunction>
    </BeginingOfMessage>
</Declaration>
```

the **final output is**

```
<Declaration>
    <Message>
        <Meduim></Meduim>
        <MessageIdentifier>AA</MessageIdentifier>
    </Message>
    <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>ISD</MessageCode>
        <MessageFunction>5</MessageFunction>
    </BeginingOfMessage>
</Declaration>
```

Comment: The question is to merge(into a single xsl solution) the above xsl with the solution xsl provided by Flack in the question below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644594/merge-functionality-of-two-xsl-files-into-a-single-file-not-a-xsl-import-or-incl

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy and general solution to any XSLT chaining of transformations. :)

Comment: Your new stylesheet to merge is just a verbose "static" look-like identity transformation. So this is just a **DUPLICATE**

Answer (score 2):

**I. Performing a chain of transformations is used quite often in XSLT applications**, though doing this entirely in XSLT 1.0 requires the use of the vendor-specific `xxx:node-set()` function. In XSLT 2.0 no such extension is needed as the infamous RTF datatype is eliminated there.

**Here is an example** (too-simple to be meaningful, but illustrating completely how this is done):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="vPass1"
        select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>2</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>10</num>
<num>14</num>
<num>18</num>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **In the first step the XML document is transformed** and the result is defined as the value of the variable `$vrtfPass1`. This copies only the `num` elements that have odd value (not even).
2. **The `$vrtfPass1` variable, being of type RTF, is not directly usable for XPath expressions** so we convert it to a normal tree, using the EXSLT (implemented by most XSLT 1.0 processors) function `ext:node-set` and defining another variable -- `$vPass1` whose value is this tree.
3. **We now perform the second transformation in our chain of transformations** -- on the result of the first transformation, that is kept as the value of the variable `$vPass1`. Not to mess with the first-pass template, we specify that the new processing should be in a named mode, called "pass2". In this mode the value of any `num` element is multiplied by two.

**See also the answer of Michael Kay to your first question, which also explained this general technique.**

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution** (no RTFs):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vPass1" >
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**III. Using the `compose()` and `compose-flist()` functions/templates of FXSL**

The **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** library provides two convenient functions/template that support easy chaining of transformations. The former composes two functions/transformations while the latter composes all functions/transformations that are provided in a sequence.

**Here is a simple, complete code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:myFun1="f:myFun1"
xmlns:myFun2="f:myFun2" 
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext myFun1 myFun2"
>
  <xsl:import href="compose.xsl"/>
  <xsl:import href="compose-flist.xsl"/>

  <!-- to be applied on any xml source -->

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <myFun1:myFun1/>
  <myFun2:myFun2/>


  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="vFun1" select="document('')/*/myFun1:*[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vFun2" select="document('')/*/myFun2:*[1]"/>
    Compose:
    (*3).(*2) 3 = 
    <xsl:call-template name="compose">
      <xsl:with-param name="pFun1" select="$vFun1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pFun2" select="$vFun2"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pArg1" select="3"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:variable name="vrtfParam">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vFun1"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vFun2"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vFun1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    Multi Compose:
    (*3).(*2).(*3) 2 = 
    <xsl:call-template name="compose-flist">
      <xsl:with-param name="pFunList" select="ext:node-set($vrtfParam)/*"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pArg1" select="2"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="myFun1:*" mode="f:FXSL">
    <xsl:param name="pArg1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="3 * $pArg1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="myFun2:*" mode="f:FXSL">
    <xsl:param name="pArg1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="2 * $pArg1"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct results are produced**:

```
Compose:
(*3).(*2) 3 = 
18

Multi Compose:
(*3).(*2).(*3) 2 = 
36
```

Comment: +1 Good and complete general answer. You should consider to post this in the original question, as this ends up to be a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Pure XSLT 1.0 does not support chaining templates (nor stylesheets as a whole).  You can either solve this program outside of XSLT by calling the second xslt template and passing it the output of the first manually, or you can use the fairly pervasive extension function `node-set()`.  MSXML, .NET, EXSL and many other implementations support such a function.  The namespace prefix for `node-set` varies depending on XSLT implementation, but the EXSL prefix is a good bet (and .NET, though undocumented, supports this).

To use `node-set` store the result of a template in an `xsl:variable` or `xsl:param` and do something like `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($myvarname)"/>`.

Finally, you can of course rewrite your two templates to provide the functionality of both in one pass - but in *general*, this isn't a trivial thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. 
The solution I posted in your last question already works.

For this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Declaration>
    <Message>
        <Meduim>#+#</Meduim>
        <MessageIdentifier>AA</MessageIdentifier>
        <CommonAccessReference></CommonAccessReference>
    </Message>
    <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>ISD</MessageCode>
        <DeclarationCurrency></DeclarationCurrency>
        <MessageFunction>5</MessageFunction>
    </BeginingOfMessage>
</Declaration>
```

Output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Declaration>
    <Message>
        <Meduim/>
        <MessageIdentifier>AA</MessageIdentifier>
    </Message>
    <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>ISD</MessageCode>
        <MessageFunction>5</MessageFunction>
    </BeginingOfMessage>
</Declaration>
```

You, in fact, don't need your original stylesheet, because basically you just copy the tree.

Comment: Actually now I need to merge your solution xsl (you provided) with the xsl in the question above. 
I am working on bpel where my base xsl is as mentioned in this question; to this xsl file I have to add two functionality which I have posted in my previous posting (for which you have provided the solution). If its still unclear i will further elaborate.

Comment: You can just replace your code in the question above with the code I provided. No need to merge anything.

Comment: The original stylesheet I have posted (in this posting) is partial, actually it has all lot of mappings and has some for-loops; when; otherwise; if conditions and to that at the end when all its mappings are done and its output is ready I need to apply the two functionality I mentioned in my previous post.

Comment: @anuamb, I'm not a telepathist. If you want someone to solve your problem, you should provide code samples, that have actual sense. There is no loops or conditional logic in your XSLT sample.

Comment: I am posting the original xsl (I will soon update that in my question); actually its a huge xsl file so I was hesitant in posting that.

Comment: Flack I will not be available for next few hours; any help appreciated.

Comment: @anuamb, I checked your edited XSLT and must say, that your input XML sample is too concise to test any solutions. And, my point stands, you still just copy the input document with minor filtering. Instead of that you should be doing identity transform (as I did in your previous question's answer) and overrirde it with necessary rules.

Comment: @Flack: I got your point but except code below rest code in my xsl is direct mapping:
 <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference = ""'>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A</xsl:text>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference"/>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
How to integrate this with your solution; help?