# Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (continuation of my previous Q's.....)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslcompiledtransform

This is in continuation of my previous questions (sorry for re-posting similar type of question again):

[Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (not a xsl import or include issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644594/merge-functionality-of-two-xsl-files-into-a-single-file-not-a-xsl-import-or-incl)

and

[Merge functionality of two xsl files into a single file (continued.....)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646329/merge-functionality-of-two-xsl-files-into-a-single-file-continued)

This is actually a bit manipulation of my second question.
I now need to merge the solution provided by **Flack** to my first question with a "choose" condition in my xsl:

```
<xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference = ""'>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A</xsl:text>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <DeclarantsReference>
              <xsl:value-of select="/Declaration/Header/DeclarantsReference"/>
            </DeclarantsReference>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Now any sample xml input like:

```
    <Declaration>
         <Message>
            <Meduim>#+#</Meduim>
            <CommonAccessReference></CommonAccessReference>
         </Message>
         <BeginingOfMessage>
            <MessageCode>5</MessageCode>
            <DeclarationCurrency></DeclarationCurrency>
            <MessageFunction>ISD</MessageFunction>
         </BeginingOfMessage>
         <Header>
            <DeclarantsReference></DeclarantsReference>
            <Items>
            <Documents>
                  <ItemDocument>
                     <DocumentCode>XXX</DocumentCode>
                     <DocumentPart></DocumentPart>
                     <DocumentLanguage>#+#</DocumentLanguage>
                  </ItemDocument>
               </Documents>
            </Items>
           </Header>
</Declaration>
```

should output:

```
<Declaration>
 <Message>
  <Meduim></Meduim>
 </Message>
 <BeginingOfMessage>
  <MessageCode>5</MessageCode>
  <MessageFunction>ISD</MessageFunction>
 </BeginingOfMessage>
 <Header>
 <DeclarantsReference>A</DeclarantsReference>
  <Items>
   <Documents>
    <ItemDocument>
     <DocumentCode>XXX</DocumentCode>
     <DocumentLanguage></DocumentLanguage>
    </ItemDocument>
   </Documents>
  </Items>
 </Header>
</Declaration>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Because you didn't choose the right solution (pipelining) you are (and will be constantly in the future) running into new problems. Your code will more and more have spaghetti-like appearance and maintainability will continuously deteriorate. It is not late to go back and revert to the pipelining solutions that were given to you earlier. Let this be a good lesson.

Comment: @Dimitre: Pipeline was not the right solution. Here we have some rules overwriting the identity rule.

Comment: @Alejandro: Then this OP is suffering from inability to explain his problem in understandable way. He obviously uses the wrong coding style, but he has not provided complete example, so one cannot help by offering a solution in a better coding style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()" name="strip">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pOutput" select="substring-before($pString,'#+#')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString,'#+#')">
                <xsl:call-template name="strip">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                                    select="substring-after($pString,'#+#')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pOutput"
                                    select="concat($pOutput,
                                                   substring-before($pString,
                                                                    '#+#'))"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($pOutput,$pString)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DeclarantsReference[not(node())]"
                  priority="1">
        <xsl:copy>A</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Declaration>
    <Message>
        <Meduim></Meduim>
    </Message>
    <BeginingOfMessage>
        <MessageCode>5</MessageCode>
        <MessageFunction>ISD</MessageFunction>
    </BeginingOfMessage>
    <Header>
        <DeclarantsReference>A</DeclarantsReference>
        <Items>
            <Documents>
                <ItemDocument>
                    <DocumentCode>XXX</DocumentCode>
                    <DocumentLanguage></DocumentLanguage>
                </ItemDocument>
            </Documents>
        </Items>
    </Header>
</Declaration>
```

**Note**: Rules overwriting the identity rule.